# How do you build an RPM for a mono application?

Tags: mono, installation, redhat, rpm

I'm need to create a distributable for a mono application I'm building.  I've figured it out for debian, but I also need to support redhat and CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

The same way as any other software. See this list of resources: https://fedorahosted.org/copr/wiki/UserDocs#HowcanIpackagesoftwareasRPM